# "let" in rspec doesn't write to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

The below does not write to my database so my tests fail:

```
let(:level_1) { Fabricate(:level, number: 1, points: 100) }       
let(:level_2) { Fabricate(:level, number: 2, points: 200) }

Level.count # 0
```

However, the following does work

```
before do
  level_1 = Fabricate(:level, points: 100, number: 1)
  level_2 = Fabricate(:level, points: 200, number: 2)
end

Level.count # 2
```

This seems very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because `let` is lazily-loaded. Meaning, only when you invoke `level1` and `level2`(inside the examples), the blocks will be executed and the records will be created. A workaround is to use `let!` which is invoked before each example.

Try

```
let!(:level_1) { Fabricate(:level, number: 1, points: 100) }       
let!(:level_2) { Fabricate(:level, number: 2, points: 200) }
```

Now, `Level.count` will return 2

For more, see https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Comment: That make since. So if I call level_1, then Level.count == 1 ? Also, I've worked on a project that didn't require me to use let! to send to the db. Is there an option I can change in spec_helper to do this?

Comment: @josh Use `let!` or define a `before` block and invoke `level_1` before each example. 
```
before do  
  level_1
  level_2
end
```
This will create the records before the example is run. I prefer `let!` as its less number of strokes.